# copy local objects by reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

Here's my problem,

```
Class MClass {

public:

    void Add(OtherClass* objects) {
        _objects = objects;
    }

private:

    OtherClass* _objects;
}

//otherfile.cpp


void Setup() {

    MClass myObj;
    OtherClass obj[NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS];

    //obj initialization here
    //...

    myObj.Add(obj);
}
```

It will cause a RT error because the *obj diminishes after the end of the function body.

But, how can make this one valid?

I like to initialized first an object before assigning it to other class.

**EDIT**

I don't want to use storage classes or something here, I just want a raw array since it is very expensive for me to use. Its functionality will not lessen my problem here.

So how do I do that in a raw-array style?

Comment: Why not just copy the object?

Comment: Well, who's going to own the objects? `MClass`? Are `OtherClass`s polymorphic?

Answer (score 2):

```
Class MClass {
public:
    void Add(std::vector<OtherClass> objects) {
        _objects = std::move(objects);
    }
private:
    std::vector<OtherClass> _objects;
}

//otherfile.cpp
void Setup() {
    MClass myObj;
    std::vector<OtherClass> obj(NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS);
    myObj.Add(std::move(obj));
}
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'd be surprised if I passed a container to a function that took it by reference and then moved from it. It should be up to the client whether they want the vector to be moved from. I guess.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this is the idiom, it allows the the caller to choose whether or not they want to move the element without having to write too functions. For example, if the caller DIDN'T want move `obj` they could remove the `std::move` at their end and it would copy, if they DID want to move it then they add `std::move`. Also a function that moves from an l-value reference is evil.

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear what you are trying to do, but you could store a collection of objects instead of a pointer:

```
class MClass 
{
 public:
    void Add(const std::vector<OtherClass>& objects) {
        objects_ = objects;
    }
    void Add(std::vector<OtherClass>&& objects) {
        objects_ = std::move(objects);
    }
 private:
    std::vector<OtherClass> objects_;
};
```

then

```
void Setup() 
{    
    MClass myObj;
    std::vector<OtherClass> obj(NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS);
    //obj initialization here
    //...
    myObj.Add(std::move(obj)); // move obj's contents onto myObs's objects.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop using raw arrays, and use either [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Then you don't have to worry about it anymore.

---

If you *really* want to do it manually, you have to copy is manually as well. Using e.g. `std::vector` and `std::move` is more effective, but here you go:

```
Class MClass {
public:
    MClass()
        : _objects(nullptr), _count(0)
    {}

    MClass(const MClass& other)
        : _objects(nullptr), _count(0)
    {
        Add(other._objects, other._count);
    }

    ~MClass()
    {
        if (_objects != nullptr)
            delete [] _objects;
    }

    void Add(const OtherClass* objects, const size_t count)
    {
        if (_objects != nullptr)
            delete [] _objects;

        _objects = new [count];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
            _objects[i] = objects[i];

        _count = count;
    }

    MClass& operator=(const MClass& other)
    {
        Add(other._objects, other._count);
    }

private:
    OtherClass* _objects;
    size_t _count;
};

// ...

myObj.Add(obj, NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS);
```

As you can see, it's a lot of more code, which makes it harder to follow and debug, and also larger possibility of errors. And not as "effective" as I said above.

Comment: but I don't want to use it in this kind of situation. Its just too expensive for me. But how can I do this in a raw-array style?

Comment: @mr5 There are answers here that show how to do it in a non-expensive way. Otherwise you have to allocate the array in the `Add` function, and manually copy all objects one by one.

Comment: @mr5 By other answers here, I mean other answers to your question here and now. See e.g. the answer from juanchopanza or 111111.

Comment: I mean, where can I find the solution using only the raw array of C++?

Comment: @mr5 Against my better judgement, please see my updated answer.

Comment: okay. But is that way too much? I don't see it expensive as the other storage classes. Any other disadvantage except for hard to debug? anyway thanks a lot for your effort there. This will help me a lot

Comment: On the Add() function, why you need to delete first the _object before copying it? sorry for asking too much

Comment: @mr5 What if you call `Add` twice? And I suggest you profile/benchmark my solution compared to the others before you dismiss them.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you store a pointer to a local array. If the method ends, the array goes out of scope and doesn't exist anymore.

This is the reason, your pointer is not valid anymore. If you want to solve this, learn about the scope of variables in C++.